# JSP an executing a code

Tags: jsp, servlets

This is pretty noob question, if I have an html button:

and when the user presses this button then I want the code in this jsp code to be run, how can I do this? or the code that I want to run should be on another .jsp page?

I guess the only way to do this would to do am a href to itself in the button?

Comment: Read the servlets tag info page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The web has the request/response lifecycle. So if you want to invoke server-side (jsp/servlet) code from client-side code (html), then you need to request a server resource. You can do that by either submitting a form, or by navigation (with a link or javascript) the URL to the target server resource.

There, you handle the request. It is preferable to do this in a servlet, and its `doGet(..)` / `doPost(..)` method(s). And then you redirect to a view (jsp, which generates html) again.

It is strongly advisable to read a book or tutorial about servlets and jsp before you start.

Comment: the html button is in a .jsp file and the code I want to execute when clicking the submit button is in that .jsp file... I just need it to be executed somehow when I press the submit button

Comment: as I said - go for a tutorial first. The JSP generates HTML, so your button is actually in the generated HTML. If you don't know the basic concepts behind servlets, I'm not about to rewrite tutorials here.

Comment: I actually did and did not quite understand it, that's why I brought this issue here. My problem is that I have a form and I want to do some code based on the form inputs...however, I don't want to go to another page after I click on submit.. I want it to stay on the same page.. however I want to be able to get the values

Comment: well, re-read my answer and graps the idea that you have client-server roundtrips on each action you want to perform.